# Why import a 10X bigger file takes way more time than 10X time of the orginal fiel in Neo4j?

Tags: csv, neo4j

Hello I am trying to import data to Neo4j by csv files.

Let's say I got 10 csv files and each of them has about 3000 rows and 2 columns. All same format.

When I import one file it takes about 30 seconds but when I combine the 10 csv files into a big csv file which now have 30000 rows and 2 columns and try to import it with the same code it takes so so much time and after forever it gives a "UnknowError". Does any one know why this happen?

Comment: can you share the code you used for loading the file(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### USING NEO4J 2.1.3

This should perform well enough, and scale linearly for files with up to 10M rows:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Label(id);

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///home/me/import/data.csv" AS line
WITH distinct line[0] as id
MERGE (:Label {id:id});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///home/me/import/data.csv" AS line
WITH distinct line[1] as id
MERGE (:Label {id:id});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///home/me/import/data.csv" AS line
WITH line[0] as id1, line[1] as id2
MATCH (n1:Label {id:id1})
MATCH (n2:Label {id:id2})
CREATE (n1)-[:REL]->(n2)
;
```

The reasons are:

- more complex merge/match + create operations pull in all the file content eagerly to separate the matching from the creation of data
- periodic commit with too large tx-size affects lookup time
- constraints are more expensive than indexes to write and not needed for single threaded inserts

Regarding your questions:

- If you change the periodic commit in the last query to 50 or 100k you see the difference.
- The time is output by the neo4j-shell.
- How many things did you import in 11s?
- Over 10M: either be more patient or use something like my [batch-inserter](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/2.1#binary-download).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question again!!! And it works much better right now if you dont mind I still have 2 questions about Neo4j and Cypher.

Comment: 1. I dont see result related to USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000??

Comment: 2. What if I want to track how much time I use to add nodes or relationships? Is that 11432ms in "return 0 rows in 11432ms"?

Comment: 3. And what if over 10M?

Comment: Updated the answer with responses to your 3 questions.

Comment: Thx and when but when I run USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///****.csv' AS line
WITH line[1] as id1
match (m:M {ID: id1}) 
set m.attribute = "NO"; "Unknowerror" again??

Comment: actually is "Java heap space
Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownFailure"